# Creating a CCSpriteFrame from texture in 3.x compared to 2.1

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

In a cocos2d 2.1 project (kobold2d), I had some code that takes pieces of a spriteframes out of sprite sheets and creates an animation. i'm having trouble getting a similar result in 3.2.1

2.1 code

```
//subclassed CCSprite
//inits a LargeSquare Sprite from within a sprite sheet
self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:theBoxFrameName andNumberOfColors:numColors];
if (self)
{
   CGRect currentRect = self.textureRect;

   //defines a new rect for the sprite that represents a small piece of the LargeSquare
   self.textureRect = CGRectMake(currentRect.origin.x+((xCoord/depth)*currentRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth),
                                  currentRect.origin.y+(((andNumberAcrossForThisDepth-1)-(yCoord/depth))*currentRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth),
                                  currentRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth,
                                  currentRect.size.height/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth
                                  );

   //finds other LargeSquares in the sprite sheet and takes similar pieces
   NSMutableArray * spritesForAnimation = [NSMutableArray array];   
   int counterer = andNumberAcrossForThisDepth*2;

   while (counterer <=64) {


        CCSprite * spritePlaceHolder;
        CCSpriteFrame * spriteFrameForAnimation;
        NSString * spriteForAnimationName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%i.png",[levelDictionary objectForKey:@"imageFrameName"],(counterer)];
        spritePlaceHolder = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteForAnimationName];

        CGRect spriteForAnimationRect = spritePlaceHolder.textureRect;
        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(spriteForAnimationRect.origin.x+((xCoord/depth)*spriteForAnimationRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth),
                                        spriteForAnimationRect.origin.y+(((andNumberAcrossForThisDepth-1)-(yCoord/depth))*spriteForAnimationRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth),
                                        spriteForAnimationRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth,
                                        spriteForAnimationRect.size.height/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth
                                        );

      spriteFrameForAnimation = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:self.texture rect:newRect];
      [spritesForAnimation addObject: spriteFrameForAnimation];
      counterer = counterer * 2;
 }

 completionAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:spritesForAnimation delay:0.2];
```

in 3.2.1 i'm having trouble getting the animation to work; i've played with everything i can think of. if i do this within the while loop rather then init a new spriteframe, i get the full LargeSprite rather than a small piece:

```
spriteFrameForAnimation = spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame;
```

and if i do this within the loop or something similar, it just is blank. i'm wondering if the issue is original Size? offset?

```
while (counterer <=64) {


        CCSprite * spritePlaceHolder;
        CCSpriteFrame * spriteFrameForAnimation;
        NSString * spriteForAnimationName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%i.png",[levelDictionary objectForKey:@"imageFrameName"],(counterer)];
        spritePlaceHolder = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteForAnimationName];

        CGRect spriteForAnimationRect = spritePlaceHolder.textureRect;
        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(spriteForAnimationRect.origin.x+((xCoord/depth)*spriteForAnimationRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth),
                                        spriteForAnimationRect.origin.y+(((andNumberAcrossForThisDepth-1)-(yCoord/depth))*spriteForAnimationRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth),
                                        spriteForAnimationRect.size.width/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth,
                                        spriteForAnimationRect.size.height/andNumberAcrossForThisDepth
                                        );

 // BEGIN NEW CODE
 CGFloat texScale = spritePlaceHolder.texture.contentScale;
 CGRect rectInPixels = CGRectMake(newRect.origin.x*texScale, newRect.origin.y*texScale, newRect.size.width*texScale, newRect.size.height*texScale);



 spriteFrameForAnimation = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:spritePlaceHolder.texture
                                                              rectInPixels:rectInPixels
                                                              rotated:NO
                                                               offset:ccp(0,0)
                                                         originalSize:originalSize.size];

      [spritesForAnimation addObject: spriteFrameForAnimation];
      counterer = counterer * 2;
 }
```

in answer to comment, i've compared several rects:

```
            CCLOG(@"newRect %f,%f,%f,%f", newRect.origin.x, newRect.origin.y, newRect.size.width,newRect.size.height);

            CCLOG(@"spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame %f,%f,%f,%f %f", spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame.rect.origin.x, spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame.rect.origin.y, spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame.rect.size.width,spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame.rect.size.height,spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame.texture.contentScale);

            CCLOG(@"rectInPixel %f,%f,%f,%f texScale %f", rectInPixels.origin.x, rectInPixels.origin.y, rectInPixels.size.width,rectInPixels.size.height,texScale);

            CCLOG(@"%@ D %i\n\n",spriteFrameForAnimation,counterer);
```

which'll output a lot of data, here's a snippet:

```
2014-09-26 16:21:03.790 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] newRect 806.000000,302.000000,100.000000,100.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.790 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame 806.000000,2.000000,400.000000,400.000000 1.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.790 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] rectInPixel 806.000000,302.000000,100.000000,100.000000 texScale 1.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.790 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] <CCSpriteFrame = 0x7fc4bb80 | Texture=(null), Rect = (806.00,302.00,100.00,100.00)> rotated:0 offset=(0.00,0.00) D 8

2014-09-26 16:21:03.791 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] newRect 404.000000,1106.000000,100.000000,100.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.791 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame 404.000000,806.000000,400.000000,400.000000 1.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.791 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] rectInPixel 404.000000,1106.000000,100.000000,100.000000 texScale 1.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.791 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] <CCSpriteFrame = 0x7fc4c030 | Texture=(null), Rect = (404.00,1106.00,100.00,100.00)> rotated:0 offset=(0.00,0.00) D 16

2014-09-26 16:21:03.791 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] newRect 404.000000,704.000000,100.000000,100.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.791 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame 404.000000,404.000000,400.000000,400.000000 1.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.791 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] rectInPixel 404.000000,704.000000,100.000000,100.000000 texScale 1.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.792 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] <CCSpriteFrame = 0x7fc4c420 | Texture=(null), Rect = (404.00,704.00,100.00,100.00)> rotated:0 offset=(0.00,0.00) D 32

2014-09-26 16:21:03.792 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] newRect 1208.000000,302.000000,100.000000,100.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.792 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] spritePlaceHolder.spriteFrame 1208.000000,2.000000,400.000000,400.000000 1.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.792 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] rectInPixel 1208.000000,302.000000,100.000000,100.000000 texScale 1.000000
2014-09-26 16:21:03.792 artThiefSB4[33484:690960] <CCSpriteFrame = 0x7fc4c750 | Texture=(null), Rect = (1208.00,302.00,100.00,100.00)> rotated:0 offset=(0.00,0.00) D 64
```

Comment: have you compared newRect (v2) with rectInPixels (v3) to see where and how they might be different (considering that the former is probably in points of course)?

Comment: i most certainly have; will add an edit. the issue is also that its completely blank so i dont think its just an offset thing.

Comment: hmmm I remember textures in v3 were at one point upside down, perhaps this is the case in general with v3 or you have the v3 version that has this upside down issue

Comment: @LearnCocos2D the pvr's are now loading from a flipped in Y texture. I had to flip all my textures from a v2.1 game in order to get the right cropping on CCSpriteFrames. You can do it with TexturePacker, but if you have a large number of them , look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701634/pvr-flipped-in-cocos2d-version-3-2-dilemma-when-porting-from-2-1/25715958#25715958.